# Run optaplanner at AWS Lambda is good enough?

Tags: deployment, optaplanner, rostering

Our expected OptaPlanner implementation would be managing 20-25 constraints (hard and soft) on a data set of 100 employees-clients and 600 visits to be assigned.

With your experience, would it be feasible the usage of AWS Lambda knowing the restriction of 15 mins? Could we get a reasonably good result with that limit if we stop OptaPlanner when it goes beyond that time?

Answer (score 2):

[OptaPlanner Benchmark](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JpcPEieU3Cg) to the rescue!

Seriously, run OptaPlanner Benchmark (see OptaPlanner docs) for 30 minutes and look at the "BEST_SCORE" graph to know what 15 minutes or more or less will get you on your machine. Then rinse and repeat on a cloud like OpenShift or AWS.

As for AWS Lamdba (serverless): [OptaPlanner Quarkus](https://quarkus.io/guides/optaplanner) is your friend.