# What is the recommended deployment for scaling timefold?

Tags: java, deployment, optaplanner, timefold

I am currently working on a timefold deployment and I wonder what is the recommended deployment strategy for scaling a timefold application. I can't find anything in the docs about it. The docs only mention some integrations https://timefold.ai/docs/timefold-solver/latest/integration/integration.

I also found some hints on azure functions [Advice on Scaling OptaPlanner using Azure Functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72651788/advice-on-scaling-optaplanner-using-azure-functions/72660411#72660411)

Which technology do you recommended Spring Boot 3.0 or Quarkus?
Do you recommended running timefold serverless as aws lambda or azure function? What are the advantages of using Quarkus over plain Java then using serverless technology?
For OptaPlanner I found some experiments with Kubernetes https://github.com/kiegroup/optaplanner-quickstarts/tree/development/technology/kubernetes. What about deploying timefold in kubernetes?

Do you recommend jvm oder native deployment?

Maybe the developers could do some recommendations to this questions.

Answer (score 0):

Serverless functions typically don't work well because running a solver takes minutes. Think HTTP session timeout: the problem submission REST request needs to be separate from the solution retrieval REST request. Or you need to use a webhook.

One pod per dataset works well, but involves a lot of orchestration to setup correctly in a scalable way.

We're working on Timefold Platform that handles all the requirements you would need or desire to run on Kubernetes.

Comment: For severless e.G. Azure Functions the idea is to trigger solving via http and getting the Answers via MessageQueue(MessageBus) to be processed by a different statefull service, that handles the results and updates the frontend. The idea is to just lift the CPU heavy solving into a function to be scalable. The major downside I see for that approach is to handle user actions like aborting the planning or doing things like pinning because serverless functions are not designed to get input after the initial trigger. However in case of Azure Functions it would be possible but not ideal.

Comment: What advantages does using quarkus have over plain java in case of timefold? Are there some performance gains using quarkus? Because I think timefold is recommending using quarkus. So I guess there are some advantages in by using it.

Comment: Quarkus is slightly faster, because it replaces reflection at build time with domain specific code. Timefold works great with plain java, with Quarkus and with Spring. Pick what fits your style best.

Comment: For serverless use cases, Quarkus with `-Pnative` (native compilation) has a huge advantage, because of the much lower startup time. The school timetabling quickstart README has info on how to compile natively.

Comment: I tried all 4 approaches today on my local machine with our planning model. Quarkus JVM, Quarkus native, plain Java JVM and plain Java native. My outcome is that plain java has lower startup times than using Quarkus. The whole timefold model init process is much faster in Quarkus, but starting the application (unitl the main method is entered) is much slower and outweights the performace gain in model parsing. Maybe its because i can't use Mandrel on my Mac or I have overlooked some other things in my local setup.

Comment: That doesn't align with my experience. Interesting. Thank you for sharing. In my experience, Quarkus starts up in like 20 milliseconds and plain Java in 1000 milliseconds. Which run commands did you use and which java version? How long was each run until the main method exactly? Mandrel and Graal Community I wouldn't expect to make a big difference.

Comment: I think I did a mistake for testing the jvm versions, because I had some other java processes running, so I think the application starts were not real coldstarts. My new results are as follows: 
Time Until Main Method: Quarkus JVM: 129ms, Quarkus Native: 650ms, Plain JVM 222ms, Plain Native: 64 ms
Time until all init stuff is done and solving starts: Quarkus JVM: 3690ms, Quarkus Native: 693ms, Plain JVM: 602ms, Plain Native: 406ms
- java version 17.0.9
- compiled by `mvn package -Dnative` pom from timefold quickstarts
- Executed with `./target/timefold-quarkus-1.0-SNAPSHOT-runner`

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with the hardware platform? I am using ARM Apple Silicon M2

Comment: It could be. But I hadn't heard that before (nor have I have seen this trend in numbers). I would try to run them on a production-like environment (= your cloud) before making conclusions.

Comment: I can confirm your values. I have created a linux vm in the cloud an compiled and executed the applications there. Now I get 24 ms for whole application startup and timefold init with Quarkus native.

Comment: Thank yo for confirming, Jonas :)